# Windows 10 AU chrome brightness change on hover

Tags: windows, google-chrome, brightness

I've recently updated my laptop to Windows 10 Anniversary update. I've noticed a certain bug, or more like a glitch, the brightness changes whenever I hover something, links/buttons... anything that changes my cursor to a pointer, this happens only on chrome.

Has anybody encountred a similar glitch ? I did a full wipe and reinstalled windows and chrome, still the same issue, graphics up to date.

Comment: This issue was resolved by an automatic update of Windows, I couldn't update Intel's drivers as it prompts me with an error saying the driver was not ment for my hardware (used both Intel releases and my manufacturer *Asus* release to update but without success)
After a while, an Windows update noted a new driver update for integrated graphics, and magic, it's now resolved. TL;DR MSFT messed up in their AU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem this morning. Solved it by going to:

Start -> Settings -> Display -> Advanced display settings -> Display adapter properties

Under the 'Adapter' tab to go Properties -> 'Driver' tab -> Update driver

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: Thanks mate, Intel was showing the driver was up to date, while it was far behind the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If the flicker problem only happens in chrome, go to chrome settings > show advanced settings > under the heading System, untick "use hardware acceleration when available"
Hope that helps :)